# Mocking cast of a Mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

i am trying to test a cast event:

The definitions:

```
private RestAPIAuthenticationFilterMod re;
ServletRequest sRequestMock;
ServletResponse sResponseMock;

@Before
public void setup() {
    re=new RestAPIAuthenticationFilterMod();
    sRequestMock  = Mockito.mock(ServletRequest.class,  withSettings().extraInterfaces(HttpServletRequest.class));
    sResponseMock = Mockito.mock(ServletResponse.class, withSettings().extraInterfaces(HttpServletResponse.class));
}
```

The line with problems:

```
 ((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader("CuentaUsuario");
```

"request" is a mock and i want to generate a response "JMUNOZ"

I tried this but it continue executing the real code:

```
    @Test
    public void onAccessDeniedNotAuthorizedIsJWTLogInAttemptTest() throws Exception {


    Subject subjectUnderTest = Mockito.mock(Subject.class);

    setSubject(subjectUnderTest);
    when(subjectUnderTest.isAuthenticated()).thenReturn(true);
    when((sRequestMock).getAttribute("whitelisted")).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);

    HttpServletRequestWrapper httpMock= Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequestWrapper.class);
    when((httpMock).getHeader("CuentaUsuario")).thenReturn("JMUNOZ");
    when(((HttpServletRequest)sRequestMock).getHeader("CuentaUsuario")).thenReturn("JMUNOZ");
    re.onAccessDenied(sRequestMock, sResponseMock);
}
```

This is my SUT:

```
  protected boolean isUserHostCallAttempt(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) {
    try {
        String userName = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader("CuentaUsuario");
        return (userName != null) && (!"".equalsIgnoreCase(userName)) && (isWhiteListed(request));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(ERROR, e);
    }
    return false;
}


   private boolean isWhiteListed(ServletRequest request) {
    if (null == request.getAttribute("whitelisted")) {
        return false;
    }
    return ((Boolean) request.getAttribute("whitelisted")).booleanValue();
}
```

The solution (without asserts):

```
 @Test
public void onAccessDeniedNotAuthorizedIsJWTLogInAttemptTest() throws Exception {
    Subject subjectUnderTest = Mockito.mock(Subject.class);
    setSubject(subjectUnderTest);
    when(subjectUnderTest.isAuthenticated()).thenReturn(true);

    HttpServletRequestWrapper httpMock= Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequestWrapper.class);

    when((httpMock).getAttribute(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
    when((httpMock).getHeader(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("JMUNOZ");
    re.onAccessDenied(httpMock, sResponseMock);
}
```

Thanks all.

Comment: the current code lacks some important parts (variable declaration/assignment) : `sRequestMock` for example or still the tested method or still same helper method as `setSubject()`. Try to make it clearer and expliciter to give us more specific hints on the issue

Comment: i added the definitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `HttpServletRequestWrapper` already extends `HttpServletRequest`, so you can mock `httpMock.getHeader` directly. Don't mock the supertype separately, create a single mock and use it in both places.

Comment: i added the definitions

Comment: How can i create the single mock?

Comment: @jaxonjma You already are: `Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequestWrapper.class)`. That object is also necessarily a `ServletRequest`.